# How i can get received date of my mail in office.js?

Tags: outlook, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am creating a web add in. I have office java script in my application. 
i am able to get all properties of email but not getting date received.
how can i get date received.What will the property to get date which is showing in my mail

i have only date created and date modified

var Email = Office.context.mailbox.item;

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.7/office.context.mailbox.item), the date created and date modified are the only date properties available.

Comment: Mail receive date is not a property that we expose as part of office.Js and there is no plan to expose that in the near future.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT "Mail receive date is not a property that we expose as part of office.Js and there is no plan to expose that in the near future". What a strange decision. Why?